# What is the name of this romantic, comedy manga?

Tags: maison-ikkoku

I read a Manga years ago that I really enjoyed but I cannot remember the name of it.

The story involved a guy, who is a student, slowly falling in love with the building manager, who moved in when he was about to leave. He ended up staying and tries to win her over but the other people in the building end up interfering. I remember they being really odd characters.

The manager is a widow. She had dark hair.

The genre was a romantic comedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manga you're looking for is [Maison Ikkoku](http://myanimelist.net/manga/688/Maison_Ikkoku).

[image]

> **The story takes place in Maison Ikkoku, a worn and aging boarding house where Godai Yuusaku, a 20 year old college applicant, lives.** Though honest and good-natured, he is weak willed and often taken advantage of by the offbeat and mischievous tenants who live with him. **As he is about to move out, he is stopped at the door by the young and beautiful Otonashi Kyouko, who announces she will be taking over as landlord. Godai immediately falls in love with her and decides to stay.**
>
> Later, **Godai and the other tenants find out that despite her young age, she is a widow,** as she married her high school teacher, but he died shortly after their marriage. Godai empathizes with her and endeavors to free her from her sadness.
>
> He manages to work up enough courage to confess his love to her, and it begins to look like that a relationship between them might actually appear... until Kyouko meets the rich, handsome, and charming Mitaka Shun. Mitaka quickly declares his intention to court Kyouko and states that he is very patient and can wait until her heart is ready.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can finally try to get hold of it again so that I can read it again.

Comment: You're welcome. It's an awesome manga. Have fun reading it.